# Android : Not Getting Unique Device_id on Samsung Galaxy Tab 

Tags: android, galaxy-tab

When I try to get device_id of my Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P1010, It returns null value. I 'm using device_id for identify unique device in my database.

I am using following code for this:

```
String device_id;

TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

device_id = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

Here I'm getting string device_id null.. This code is working fine for my all other device, HTC, LG, Google NExxus ICS etc..

Please give me solution for it ASAP.

Thanks,
Jay Patel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your requirement is only to generate unique identification of device, you can use the below code:

```
UUID id=UUID.randomUUID();

//store this in shared pref     
String device_id=id.toString();

//later fetch it from share pref
UUID Id=UUID.fromString(device_id);
```

This is the standard way of recognising the device according to [RFC4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt)

Answer (score 2):

`getDeviceId()` returns the device's IMEI or MEID, which is tied to the device's SIM card.  It sounds like your Galaxy Tab is a wi-fi only device, and has no SIM card; that's why it's not giving you a valid device id.

Unfortunately there is no way to get a device id from a wi-fi only device; I'd suggest using ANDROID_ID or some other id if you get a `null` value for `getDeviceId()`.

Comment: Is the guaranteed that the Android ID will be an unique identifier.??

Comment: There are issues with ANDROID_ID, namely it can be reset on a device wipe and it is not reliable pre-Android 2.2.  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html  Other possible identifiers are MAC address or hardware serial, but both of these also have potential issues.